# Tell systemd to output every command it executes for a unit

Tags: systemd, coreos

I'm trying to run some Docker container on coreos. However, I'm getting some error and is clueless about what went wrong.

What I did is to use `journalctl -f -u myunit.service` to view the log in realtime, and then use `systemctl start myunit.service` and `systemctl stop myunit.service` to trigger the action, however I don't see any thing details enough to understand what's going on.

I would like systemd to output all commands it execute while it starts or stops my unit. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Run `systemctl status myunit.service` and you will see the commands that were run, and their status.